# Validate XML using ONLY root XSD (Java)

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I've went on an on searching for something that could help me, but with no success, so I'm turning to you.

I'm writing a code in Java that need to validate XMLs against given dynamic schemas. I'm given 2 XSDs that one references an element from the other one.
The requirement is that **only** XMLs which are using the elements in the root XSD will be valid. An example will clear things up.

Example of XSDs

The first one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://root/beer" 
        xmlns="http://root/beer" xmlns:chl="http://child/earth"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:import namespace="http://child/earth" schemaLocation="testing_child.xsd"/>

<xs:element name="head">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="chl:banana"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The Second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://child/earth"
        xmlns="http://child/earth"  elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="banana">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="leaf" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now, I want that the following XML will be valid:

```
<head xmlns="http://root/beer">
 <banana xmlns="http://child/earth">
    <leaf>yo</leaf>
 </banana>
</head>
```

BUT (and that's the tricky bit), this one won't:

```
<banana xmlns="http://child/earth">
    <leaf>yo</leaf>
</banana>
```

I tried using Validator with SAX and DOM, using LSResourceResolver and without, but came with the same result - both XMLs are valid and not only the parent(/root) one.... 
I can't use JAXB because I can't build classes out of the XSDs (they are kept in files in the fs).
And no, I can't change the XSDs either.

If you know of a way / have done something similar in the past and could help me, I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly XML Schema conform, no compliant validator should complain about `banana` as the top-level element.

So you need something extra.

I was initially thinking about making `banana` an abstract element via interim processing in the resource resolver. But there may be valid usages for `banana` as a non-root element (via `xs:element/@ref`, for instance).

So I would suggest doing some additional validation - either via something like Schematron or just "write your own in Java".

You're probably using Xerces in Java.

- You can go inside the `Schema` object and find out top-level elements and their locations.
- Then you can gather QNames of just those elements which are located in your "root" schema.
- Finally, you just check the QName of the document element against that set.

This is how I'd do it. This will tie you to the validator implementation, but your customization is proprietary anyway.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore for your reply. By the time I saw it, I did exactly as you suggested... posting it for others' use. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As @lexicore suggested, I added extra validation code (not the prettiest thing I wrote, but it works for now).

If anyone's intersted:

```
public static void validate(String fileLocXSD, String fileLocXML) {
     try {
         boolean valid = false;

         // Read data to strings 
         String xsd = dataFromFile(fileLocXSD);
         xsd = xsd.toLowerCase();
         String xml = dataFromFile(fileLocXML);
         xml = xml.toLowerCase();

         // Notice that parsing errors may occure 
         Document doc = getDocument(xsd);
         Document docXML = getDocument(xml); 

         // Let's strip down the xsd and get what we want 
         ArrayList<String> listHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();  
         Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
         NodeList listElements = docElement.getChildNodes();

         String ns = docElement.getAttribute("targetnamespace");
         ns = ns==null?"":ns;

         // Check all child elements of the doc element
         for (int i=0; i<listElements.getLength(); i++) {

             Node node = listElements.item(i);

             if (node.getNodeName().contains("element")) {
                 listHeaders.add(((Element)node).getAttribute("name"));
             }

         }

         // What about the xml ha? don't forget about it (or about Dre) 
         Element docXMLElement = docXML.getDocumentElement();
         String nsXML = "";
         String rootName = docXMLElement.getNodeName();

         // Default ns in xml
         if (!rootName.contains(":")) {

             nsXML = docXMLElement.getAttribute("xmlns");
             nsXML = nsXML==null?"":nsXML;

             // No namespace
             if (("").equals(ns) && ("").equals(nsXML)) {

                 for (int j=0; (j<listHeaders.size()) && (!valid); j++) {
                     if (listHeaders.get(j).equals(rootName)) {
                         valid = true;
                     }
                 }

             } else if ((ns).equals(nsXML)) {

                 for (int j=0; (j<listHeaders.size()) && (!valid); j++) {
                     if (listHeaders.get(j).equals(rootName)) {
                         valid = true;
                     }
                 }
             }

         } else {

             String shortNS = rootName.substring(0,rootName.indexOf(":"));
             nsXML = docXMLElement.getAttribute("xmlns:"+shortNS);
             rootName = rootName.substring(rootName.indexOf(":")+1);

             // has to be namespace in xsd
             if ((ns).equals(nsXML)) {

                 for (int j=0; (j<listHeaders.size()) && (!valid); j++) {
                     if (listHeaders.get(j).equals(rootName)) {
                         valid = true;
                     }
                 }
             } 
         }

         System.out.println(valid?"valid":"nope");  

     }  catch (SAXParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Parsing error: "+e.getMessage());
     }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("holy shit: "+e.getMessage());
     }
 }

 public static String dataFromFile(String fileLoc) {

     String xml = "";
     try {
         BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileLoc),"UTF-8")); 
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while((line = b.readLine()) != null) {                
             builder.append(line);
         } 
         xml = builder.toString();
         xml = xml.trim().replaceFirst("^([\\W]+)<","<");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Error reading file");
     }
     return xml;
 }

 public static Document getDocument(String xml) throws Exception {
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
     factory.setValidating(false);
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
     return doc;
 }
```